# Installation did not succed

Tags: android, android-studio

After update to Android Studio 3.5 I can't run my application on a real device.

The only thing that I can see is the following output

```
08/27 07:28:00: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi 4.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: ''pm install-create -r -t -S 5143592' returns error 'UNSUPPORTED''
```

Comment: Nope. I have no error in the **build output**.

Comment: I didn't solved it yet. Maybe it's something wrong with my phone?

Comment: Yes, it is running on emulator.

Comment: Ok I got it..Whenever you run the app in **Xiaomi** then  there is dialog appears (For 10 seconds) before your application launch, On dialog there will be two option install and cancel, you need to click install option on the dialog(before 10 seconds) to run app otherwise you will get the error which , you are getting now,, try it and let me know

Comment: @paweo90 any luck with this? getting something similar

Comment: @ono Yes solustion from G-Shadow solve my problem. You have to disable MIUI optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's Xiaomi try go to Developer Settings and disable "MIUI optimization". It helps in my case. Have no idea why though.
Source: [Installation did not succeed on Android Studio 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57735512/installation-did-not-succeed-on-android-studio-3-5) (see last comment).

Answer (score 0):

uninstall your app before install

then invalidate and cash clean `Android Studio`

***File > Invalidate Caches / Restart***

Answer (score 0):

You just removed the error in your project, which is not coming yet on your **`Logcat`** but it appears in the **`Build`** for this you need to follow this steps.

First, you need to click on the **`Build`** option which appears at the bottom of the Android-studio like in below image

[image]

And then after you will get the at the left options of the Studio like below
[image]

You need to click this option like this [image]

When you will click on the above option then, you will get **`Build Output`** as in my second image. In my case, there is no any error or exception therefor all white text appear in the second image.  In your case, you definitely get error or exceptions then you need to resolve it to get rid from the problem. I have done the same process , as above in my case.